# Can't reads dot-separated integers

Tags: haskell, ghc

While trying to read a list of dot-separated integers, I've noticed a strange thing.

```
Prelude> (reads "123") :: [(Integer,String)]
[(123,"")]
Prelude> (reads "123.") :: [(Integer,String)]
[(123,".")]
Prelude> (reads "123.456") :: [(Integer,String)]
[]
```

I understand why it happens in terms of the implementation (`readNumber` succeeds and then `convert` fails), and I understand how to use `readDec` to overcome it.

My question is, is this behaviour documented somewhere in the report? If so, why?

Comment: Good catch.  My guess is there is a regex equivalent of `\d+\.\d+` matching a Double and fails to match Integer.  I also doubt that you can ever get more than one element since it will greedily match everything after the first Integer to the String.

Comment: This sounds a bit buggy to me. That said, `Read` is intended primarily to parse things that look like Haskell, and nothing that looks like Haskell will sensibly accept `"123." ++ anything` except as a `Fractional` literal.

Comment: @dfeuer How sure of that are you? `:t 123.456e3` => `123.456e3 :: Num a => a` with `NumDecimals` turned on. ;-)

Comment: @DanielWagner, woah!  That is some corner case magic.

Comment: Anyhow I call this a bug. [bug report](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ReportABug)?

Comment: Or maybe not?  `lex "123.45"` gives a single token, so if you wear tokenizer glasses, you didn't actually find an integer...

Comment: @luqui, I do believe the current behavior merits a note in the user's guide.

Comment: @DanielWagner, that's a good point, I suppose, although I'd probably argue it shouldn't be handled in the parser, and I'd guess it probably isn't. I imagine that's parsed as a `Fractional a` and then GHC makes note of the fact that in fact its `Rational` representation has a denominator of `1`.

Comment: Seems very much like a bug to me. As a user, I don't really care how it's implemented — parser, shmarser, whatever. This is inconsistent.

Comment: Rolled the title back to `reads`. The function is called `reads`, please leave it as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only is this not documented in the report, it appears to be *at variance* from the report.

There are many places where for efficiency reasons or otherwise the GHC standard libraries diverge from the reference implementations in the Report. But, unless carefully noted, the implementations should match behavior.

However, if we look at the [relevant part](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch9.html#verbatim-307) of the Haskell Report, we see

```
instance  Read Int  where  
  readsPrec p r = [(fromInteger i, t) | (i,t) <- readsPrec p r]  
        -- Reading at the Integer type avoids  
        -- possible difficulty with minInt

instance  Read Integer  where  
    readsPrec p         = readSigned readDec
```

We see that it uses a different implementation that I don't think has this behavior.

So this is something that certainly should be raised to the libraries list at haskell.org.